# javascript GET method

Tags: javascript, jquery, get

I'm making a webapp and when I try to make a call using GET method, despite the url and key being right, I always fail

html code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>cerca</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/main.js"></script>
</head>
<br>
<p><img src="img/Bip.png" height="150" width="150"/>
    Bip business integration partners
</p>


<h1>Cerca</h1>

<form onsubmit="foundTopic()">

<input name="mioTesto" type="text" id="topicID" placeholder ="Cerca per topic " size="40" maxlength="200" />
<button type="submit" >Cerca</button>

</form><br></br>



<form onsubmit="foundActivities()">

<input name="mioTesto" type="text" id="activitiesID" placeholder="Cerca per activities" size="40" maxlength="200" />
<button type="submit">Cerca</button>


</form><br>

<h5><a href="index.html">home</h5>

</body>
</html>
```

js code

```
function foundTopic() {

    var topic = document.getElementById("topicID").value;
    var url2 = "http://localhost:8080/bip/workTagsTopic/" + encodeURI(topic)
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "http://localhost:8080/bip/workTagsTopic/" + encodeURI(topic),
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data, status, jqXHR) {
            // do something
            console.log("okS")
        },
        error: function (jqXHR, status) {
            console.log( url2)
            console.log( topic)

        }
    });
}
```

In the console it prints this:
http://localhost:8080/bip/workTagsTopic/key2        main.js:17
key2                                                main.js:18

Comment: is the url is hitting ?

Comment: yes is hutting, if I click on the written link it open the page with the list

Comment: Is it working with $.get

Comment: whit $.get it doesn't work, not found the "topic"

Comment: @DanieleLorenzetti ...  Can you console **jqXHR, status** in error & let us know what you are getting in the console...

Comment: I'm trying other REST methods and maybe the problem is the cors ( Cross-Origin Resource Sharing )

Answer (score 0):

if your js code is exactly written as you've mentioned above then you should put semicolons after few lines.

```
var url2 = "http://localhost:8080/bip/workTagsTopic/" + encodeURI(topic);
```

and also where the all console.log() line are written. Also check again your paths. Besides these, your code seems okay. Try it.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure very much, try this

```
function foundTopic(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    // blablabla
}
```

just prevent the default `submit` event.